Google cloud app engine never shutdown nodejs
as said in the title, my app engine API is always active and generating full time charges.
Basically, it always has 100% traffic allocation, even without receiving requests for more than 8 hours.
My app.yaml:

runtime: nodejs



env: flex



- automatic_scaling:



 max_instances: 1



-runtime_config:



 operating_system: ubuntu22



-env_variables:



 LOCATION: GCLOUD



 GITHUB_TOKEN:*****


I try tô set min instances 0, but dont deploy.
Im app engine version show these configs:
runtime: nodejs
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
env_variables:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: >-
automatic_scaling:
  cool_down_period: 120s
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
liveness_check:
  initial_delay_sec: '300'
  check_interval_sec: '30'
  timeout_sec: '4'
  failure_threshold: 4
  success_threshold: 2
readiness_check:
  check_interval_sec: '5'
  timeout_sec: '4'
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: '300'
service_account: *****
flexible_runtime_settings:
  operating_system: ubuntu22

If someone with more experience can help me, im Very gratefull!
tried to set min instances in 0, dont work.
Tried to config app.yam like standard, but im deploy time only loading and after some minutes crash, my standard app.yamp:
runtime: nodejs18
env: standard

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

network: 
session_affinity:true


Flex env never scale to 0. Only standard do. But if you have a container, you can try (and prefer) Cloud Run instead.

As Guillaume said in the comments, App engine flexible do not scale down to 0. Also, App engine standard has a free tier and App engine flexible has no free tier.
You can look in the documentation for more info:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing

i tried standar with the configs when i show in the post, but never deploy only in infinity loop.

Here is what I use for this in app.yaml:
